# My desktop application tray icon showing multiple

Tags: c#, .net, windows, exe, system-tray

Here, In my application, I disappear the form, if my process stop, i restart the process, that time new tray icon will appear, previous icon doesn't disappeart.    Please help to hide tray icons those proceses are ended.

I want to hide the tray icon, code and i want to know where i have to write the code.

Comment: It's a known issue, and it is actually the responsibilty of the Windows OS. If you hover with the mouse over the icons of the old instances, they will disappear.

Comment: @wohlstad yes, that was disappeared but is there any way to hide programmatically